# как добавить данные в базу через форму. MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin, form

Есть форма статьи:

```
<form method="POST" action="news.php">
<label for="">Заголовок</label>
<input name="title" type="text" placeholder="Введите заголовок">
<label  for="">Добавьте изображение</label>
<input name="picture" type="file">
<label for="">Описание</label>
<input name="decr" type="text" placeholder="Добавьте описание">
<button type="submit">Опубликовать</button>
</form>
```

На MyPhpAdmin создана база с таблицей users и news. В users находится информация о пользователях с их данными, в таблице news содержится информация о статьях.
Так вот, нужно по нажатию на кнопку, добавлять данные в таблицу и выводить их на странице news.php. Так же не знаю, как сделать вывод логина с которого была отправлена запись.

в news.php находится следующий код, который должен выводить содержимое таблицы

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    require_once 'connect.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$picture = $_POST['picture'];
$descr = $_POST['descr'];

$add = $connect->query("INSERT INTO 'users' ('id','username', 'picture', 'descr') VALUES (NULL,'$username', '$picture','$descr')");
if ($add == true){
    echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
}else{
    echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
}
?>
```

Всё это планируется разместить внутри блока и применить стили.

Comment: а что у вас ужЕ написано в php файлах?

Comment: Как минимум у полей нет имён. И приведите содержимое news.php

Comment: Добавил news.php

Comment: Те или иные кавычки в тексте запроса имеют разные значения. Прежде чем бездумно их пихать - следует прочитать что они значат.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляем в БД.

```
$host         = 'localhost';
$database     = 'nameDB';
$userName     = 'root';
$userPassword = '';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $userName, $userPassword);
$dbh->exec('SET NAMES UTF8');

$stm = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (NULL, :username, :picture, :descr);');
$stm->bindValue(':username', 'username');
$stm->bindValue(':picture', 'picture');
$stm->bindValue(':descr', 'descr');
$stm->execute();
```

Выводим из БД.

```
$stm = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE');
$stm->execute();

$allInformation = $stm->fetchAll();
```